# "No module named 'bs4'" Even though bs4 is already satisfied on python 3.7?I

Tags: python

I already have bs4 installed for anaconda and python 3, however when running some code in vscode it says that it can't find the bs4 module.

```
Successful Traceback in shell
Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4 in /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from bs4) (4.9.0)
Requirement already satisfied: soupsieve>1.2 in /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from beautifulsoup4->bs4) (1.9.3)
(base) Joshuas-MacBook-Pro:~ joshuag$ 

Fail traceback in VSCode
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3 /Users/joshuag/PycharmProjects/ThingsToKnow/WebScraping.py (base) Joshuas-MacBook-Pro:PycharmProjects joshuag$ /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3 /Users/joshuag/PycharmProjects/ThingsToKnow/WebScraping.py Traceback (most recent call last): –
```

Comment: are you using virtual env? or you may have multiple version of python installed

Comment: No I don't believe I am using a virtual env (sorry im a noob), and maybe it's a big mess so I'm not quite sure what to do

Comment: add the full traceback of your error

Comment: also show the install successful traceback

Comment: Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4 in /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from bs4) (4.9.0)
Requirement already satisfied: soupsieve>1.2 in /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from beautifulsoup4->bs4) (1.9.3)
(base) Joshuas-MacBook-Pro:~ joshuag$

Comment: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3 /Users/joshuag/PycharmProjects/ThingsToKnow/WebScraping.py
(base) Joshuas-MacBook-Pro:PycharmProjects joshuag$ /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3 /Users/joshuag/PycharmProjects/ThingsToKnow/WebScraping.py
Traceback (most recent call last):

Comment: not here, add it in the question

Comment: well you have it installed in 3.7 and you are trying to call it in 3.8

Comment: what do I type in the terminal to get it to install in 3.8?

Comment: well you have an answer, try it

Answer (score 1):

It smells to me like you have multiple pyhton versions:

1. in visual code type `Ctrl+Shift+P`
2. selecte Python select interpreter

[image]

3. From the list (sample image)
   Select Python 3.7.

You were getting the error because you installed it for 3.8, not 3.7
[image]

Source: [VS Doc](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments)